# Which of these is more efficient to choose a function?

Tags: c

So lets say I have 2 functions to choose from based on whether number is even or odd. I came up with this:

`(void (*[])()){f1 ,f2}[n%2]();`.

Is it more or less efficient than simply:

`n%2 ? f2() : f1();`

Comment: why don't you compile and inspect the assembler produced?  Do you actually have a performance bottneck? If not, use the form that is most readable and understandable.

Comment: I am not that advanced. And I am just a student. Not creating anything in particular. I am just curious about this.

Comment: Which one is easier to read? Picking based on "efficiency" is just premature optimization in this case.

Comment: @nescius: then why not find out how to do that and improve your skillset?

Comment: I think there's a very good chance the compiler will generate the same code for both. If not, the difference will be negligible.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Comment: The first version is practically unreadable. I've been programming for 40+ years, and I would have to think hard to realize what it's doing. Unless there's a really good reason, use the second version.

Comment: `if (n%2 == 0) f1(); else f2();` As I just wrote that, I realize that both options you've given do not produce the same result. The first option will call `f1` if n%2 == 0, and the second option will call `f2` for the same reason. This is probably why it is better to more expressive than worrying about trivial optimizations

Comment: @Barmar: He doesn't care because `n` is a coin flip (thus RNG) and I depended (loosely) on it in my answer.

Comment: Just so you know, your two implementations are not equivalent.  In the first statement, `f1()` is invoked if `n` is even.  In the other statement, `f1()` is invoked when `n` is odd. **Just saying...** :)

Comment: Oh right fixed the mistake.

Comment: But lets say we have more functions to choose from. The first one is easier to expand.

Comment: Always choose an implementation for readability.  Then, when the program is finished, if it is too slow you profile it and find out where the slowest bit is and try to fix that.  Usually, anything not called millions of times in a loop will not be a problem.  Doing optimizations to make it faster before the whole program is finished means that all the time you spend is probably waster.  In this case readability means: coose the if statement one until you have enough functions that the array version is more readable and then switch to that.

Comment: One way to make the first more readable is to use a typedef for the function pointer.  Then it is just as readable as the second.  The second version is faster but the difference in a whole program is negligible.  For example:https://quick-bench.com/q/DkpccQY2k70aNz12ZZm20Nb6JbQ  The rand() function to get a random number for n is way slower than either of the function invocation methods.

Comment: @Barmar: I had the advantage. `(condition?fork():vfork())` might be wrong by `vfork`'s spec, but `(condition?fork:vfork)()` is clearly fine. So having analyzed that problem I could read this one. (For production I used `if (condition) pid = fork(); else pid = vfork();` which is also clearly fine.)

Comment: @nescius If you have more functions to choose from, `switch/case` would be the appropriate syntax. It will be compiled into a jump table, so there's no efficiency lost.

Answer (score 3):

Profile it; most likely too small to measure.

Assuming a naive compiler, the second will be a lot shorter to execute. But the first is written terribly; could be squashed down to

```
((n1&1) ? f1 : f2)();
```

now it's pretty much a toss-up. the first generates something like

```
test al, 1
jz +3
call f1
jmp +1
call f2
```

and the second something like

```
test al, 1
jmp +3
lea  rcx, [f1]
jmp +1
lea  rcx, [f2]
call rcx
```

but a good optimizer could flatten that down to

```
lea  rcx, [f1]
test al, 1
cmovcc rcx, f2
call rcx
```

while all this is true; the initial statement applies. It's most likely too small to measure.

Additional question in comments involving "easier to expand"; well yes. After a surprisingly short number of functions, the array lookup becomes faster. I'm skeptical of things and would not write the array inline but somebody could come along and prove me wrong. If there's more than two I would write

```
static  void (*dispatch_table[])() = {f1 ,f2};
dispatch_table[n % (sizeof(dispatch_table) / sizeof(dispatch_table[0]))]();
```

This complex mod expression compiles to a compile-time constant; which lets the compiler optimize out the `%` to something more performant; it's written as so so that adding more entries doesn't require changing the second argument to `%` when adding to the array.

As is being pointed out in comments I didn't handle `n` negative. Most RNG sources don't generate negative numbers.

Comment: Intention on the first one was me trying to choose a function without if else or '?'.

Comment: note: `n1&1` would give the wrong result for negative numbers on a ones-complement machine

Comment: @M.M: Did C ever add a specification for what % of negative does? My books are pretty old but say don't trust it.

Comment: @nescius: You're going to pay one branch miss penalty anyway. Indirect jump needs a few instructions between to not pay.

Comment: It's always been defined such that `(a/b)*b + a%b == a` .   The `a/b` part always truncates towards zero now, but prior to C99 it was implementation-defined whether truncating towards or away from zero

Comment: Joshua, Note that `n%2` is not used by OP as in `n % 2`, but as `n % 2 == 0` - so easy for the _compiler_ to emit efficient code of a single bit test.  With `n1&1` you gain with a weak compiler, but lose clarity (and portably to some old dinosaur 1s' complement machine).  I find either easy to read.  Code to your group's coding standard.

Comment: @M.M: So `n%2` will also be bad for your lookup table when `n` is negative.

Answer (score 1):

Godbolt to the rescue (64-bit Clang 11.0 with -O3 optimizations):  https://godbolt.org/z/MWjPnn

First implementation:

```
void impl1(int n)
{
    (void (*[])()){evenfunc ,oddfunc}[n%2]();
}

    mov     qword ptr [rsp - 16], offset evenfunc()
    mov     qword ptr [rsp - 8], offset oddfunc()
    mov     eax, edi
    shr     eax, 31
    add     eax, edi
    and     eax, -2
    sub     edi, eax
    movsxd  rax, edi
    jmp     qword ptr [rsp + 8*rax - 16]    # TAILCALL
```

Second implementation:

```
void impl2(int n)
{
    n%2 ? oddfunc() : evenfunc();
}

        test    dil, 1
        jne     .LBB1_1
        jmp     evenfunc()                    # TAILCALL
.LBB1_1:
        jmp     oddfunc()                     # TAILCALL
```

Comment: So that means the second one is better right ?

Comment: @nescius Are conditional branches cheap or expensive compared to the first branchless implementation? You really should profile the code on the target system to know for certain.

Comment: I am getting bombarded with difficult terms for me to understand :D I am just a student not doing anything specific. Just a question out of curiosity.

Comment: @nescius Modern processors (and memory systems) are complicated. It's not always simple to know which will be "faster" in the context of a larger program. Good engineering advice usually is to measure often.

Comment: @nescius For example, on a CPU with a [branch predictor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor) the second one might be slower because the prediction could be wrong 50% of the time.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: But the first one will be wrong 100% of the time. `rax` isn't stable yet so it predicts the next instruction.

Comment: Let me help clear this up.  **Micro-optimizations will lead to micro-results**.  Start with the most readable code. If your program doesn't meet performance goals, profile it and identify where it's slow.  Fix that first before you start trying to optimize the binary jump table.

Comment: That's some pretty heinous optimization in the first case

Comment: Here is a quickbench measure for each.  The if statement version is faster on their machine: https://quick-bench.com/q/DkpccQY2k70aNz12ZZm20Nb6JbQ  I used a random number for n so the branch prediction in the second one should be awful.